# Grid view in xml android

Tags: android, xml, gridview, layout, imagebutton

I want to display `ImageButtons` in `GridView`. Currently I am using `RelativeLayout`.

Here is my XML code:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.easy.convert.MainActivity" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/btnbitsbytes" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnmassweight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnbitsbytes"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/btnmassweight" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ButtonConvert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnmassweight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnmassweight"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/btnlength" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ButtonConvert"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ButtonConvert"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/btntemperature" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/btndistance" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:src="@drawable/btnaboutus" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I dont know how to use GridView or any other Layout but i want my layout to look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `ScrollView` with `GridView`. The gridview widget has its own scroll detection which it can disturbe the scrollview scroll. I'd suggest you a few thing to achieve what you want, try to put inside your scrollview a `TableLayout`, this will be more adapted:

```
<ScrollView ... >
    <RelativeLayout ... >
        <TableLayout ...>
            <TableRow>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
                 <ImageButton>
            </TableRow>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Or you can just add 3 `LinearLayout`s and set the `weight` attribute of each children to `1`, your layout will be something like that:

```
<ScrollView ... >

    <RelativeLayout ... >

        <LinearLayout ...
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3" >

            <ImageButton   ...
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton  ...
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton  ...
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

`weightSum` set to `3` indicates the number of columns in the linearlayout and `layout_weight` indicates that each child will fill `1` column.

But if you absolutely want a `GridView`, you'll need this layout:

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

You'll also need an `Adapter` to display your image inside. You should read this topic: [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). **But a GridView doesn't allow to have a footer view** like your Button "About us"..
To keep the Button *"About us"* at the end, you need a custom adapter for your gridview, maybe this will help you: [HFGridView](https://github.com/SergeyBurish/HFGridView) - It works like `addFooterView` for `ListView`.

Comment: As I can see on your screenshot, I will be more easy and more adapted to use tablelayout instead of gridview when you just have 9 images.. ;)

Comment: No actually I am thinking to add more images (options). Will TableLayout create problems with different screen sizes..?

Comment: No, but it will be heavy if you have multiple images (like 20, even more) because, it's all display manually not dynamically like GridView or ListView which use an adapter to display the row layout. I mean you will have to write all 20 views in your layout.. You see?